# JCR vs. CMIS: Which repository API should I use?

Tags: repository, jcr, cmis

I am starting a new project that needs to connect to a repository that offers [JCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java) and [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) APIs.

The project is in Java and both APIs offer every operation we need.
What API would you chose and why? JCR or CMIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JCR API is quite a bit more feature-rich than CMIS, so you should check if you need any features that are not covered by CMIS.
You might also be interested in this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130601011646/http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2009/05/jcrcmiscomparison.html) comparing CMIS and JCR

Comment: working link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130601011646/http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2009/05/jcrcmiscomparison.html

Answer (score 2):

CMIS has been adopted by [most ECM vendors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services#CMIS_Servers), while JCR implementations are [rather rare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java#Available_implementations).

If both APIs offer the operations you need, then choose CMIS, it will be more interoperable, allowing you to switch from a repository to another without much hassle.

Comment: Furthermore it looks some big actors have dropped JCR in favour of CMIS http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/why-nuxeo-dropped-jcr/